# gnuradio packet size overflow

Tags: gnuradio, gnuradio-companion

I am working with gnuradio, and I have overflow exception - 'O' that
gets prints each second.
I wanted to know the size of the samples that get drops with each 'O'.
When I monitored the USB connection on Wireshark I saw that the each packet getting from the device is in size of
8256 Bytes, so according to the logic that each O represent one packet missing
this is the size. But I not sure, so I would like your help.
Thanks!

I also looked online but I didn't found some concrete size, maybe I
am missing something.

Comment: the size is not the critical thing here – your computer is not picking up the samples from your SDR device (probably a USRP?) quickly enough.

Comment: Hi, this I know. I wanted to calculate the probability that I receive/miss some signal. for a given system with this number of zeros in sec.

Comment: Uff, that will be a rather hard to model thing, because missing a package comes with additional computational overhead, and hence, the arrival process of O (these are letters "capital O" live "overflow", not number "0") is by no means a markov chain. Plus, the things that effect your system's ability to process samples in time are already inherently non-stationary. I don't think you'll get far with a simple probabilistic approach that says "there's probability X to miss N samples".